# Count how many times a substring appears in a string

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, while-loop

i am trying to count how many times a substring does appear in a string.

```
count = 0
stock = []
phrase = "abcdacdeabcf"
sub = "abc"
liphrase = list(phrase) 
lisub = list(sub)

for j in range(0,len(liphrase)-len(lisub)+1):
    for i in range(0,len(lisub)) :
        if liphrase[i+j] == lisub[i]:
            stock.append(liphrase[i+j])
    if stock == lisub:
        count += 1
        stock = []

print(count)
```

I wrote this code but it doesn't seem to work well and can't figure out the problem.
I would appreciate any help, thanks :)

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work well" is not a clear enough description of what doesn't work. Please be *very* specific, with a well chosen, hardocoded input, and the corresponding vs expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue with your code is that you forgot to reset the stock list in the case where the inner loop doesn't find a match. So, even if one substring doesn't match, those characters are still being accumulated in the stock list.

However, instead of using the stock list to accumulate characters and then compare it to lisub, you can use a flag to determine if a substring matches. If the flag is still true after looping over the substring, you can increment the count.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
count = 0
phrase = "abcdacdeabcf"
sub = "abc"
liphrase = list(phrase)
lisub = list(sub)

for j in range(0, len(liphrase) - len(lisub) + 1):
    match_found = True  # assume a match until proven otherwise
    for i in range(0, len(lisub)):
        if liphrase[i + j] != lisub[i]:
            match_found = False
            break  # exit the inner loop if no match
    if match_found:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Or you can use [count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) method

```
phrase = "abcdacdeabcf"
sub = "abc"
count = phrase.count(sub)
print(count)
```

Comment: Perfect use case for `for`-`else`, no need to reinvent it.

Comment: And since you dropped the list building/comparison, there's no need for the list versions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to compare each substring with a single loop:

```py
def count_occurences(phrase: str, sub: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(phrase) - len(sub) + 1):
        if phrase[i:i+len(sub)] == sub:
            count += 1
    print('DEBUG:', 'Built-in:', phrase.count(sub), '|', 'Custom:', count)
    return count
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = count_occurences('abcdacdeabcf', 'abc')
    print(count) # 2
    print(count_occurences('a', 'a')) # 1
```

As Kelly mentioned in the comments, you could use `startswith`:

```py
def count_occurences(phrase: str, sub: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    for start in range(len(phrase) - len(sub) + 1):
        if phrase.startswith(sub, start):
            count += 1
    return count
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count_occurences('abcdacdeabcf', 'abc')) # 2
    print(count_occurences('a', 'a')) # 1
```

Here's a little code golf with list comprehension:

```py
''' 74 bytes '''
f=lambda p,s:len([i for i in range(len(p)-len(s)+1) if p.startswith(s,i)])

print(f('abcdacdeabcf', 'abc')) # 2
print(f('a', 'a')) # 1
```

Comment: @KellyBundy my bad, I missed that. I need more coffee.

Comment: Code golf usually doesn't care about speed, btw, so you could remove the `-len(s)`. (Saving a few more bytes: `f=lambda p,s:sum(p.startswith(s,i)for i in range(len(p)+1))`)